# simple red5 chat

Tags: red5, videochat

i want to create simple red5 video chat, consisting of two swf, one for showing the video of the user from webcam which is easy, the problem that i am having is how to get the video of the other user in the second swf file from the server,
Basically i want to connect the swf files with the php and mysql so the respective users can connect with each other,
Does any one have an example or something to work with as i am stuck here, i have also searched the net on this topic but most off the video chat tutorials are complex ones.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://www.red5chat.com/

This may help you.